# Trigger click on HTML 5 color picker with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, color-picker

Within JQuery we are able to trigger 'click' on any given element with:

```
$(selector).trigger('click');
```

Though i have difficulties doing so when the element is a HTML 5 color picker and the 'display' property is set to 'none' by CSS.

Normally we can do this if the input type is 'file' or ...

So is there anyway to get this done with JQuery or plain javascript?

**HTML elements**

```
input type="color" id="fontSel" style="display: none;"
div id="fontWrap"
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#fontWrap").click(function(){
     $("#fontSel").trigger("click");
});
```

**ANSWER**

Change the style to:

```
input type="color" id="fontSel" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px;"
```

Comment: Are you saying you're able to trigger the click when the input is visible ?

Comment: You can only trigger it if user click somewhere in document

Comment: If the element doesn't have a default click functionality, or, the element doesn't have a `.click()` event bound by jQuery, then this will not work. If it's something like `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> Go! </a>`, jQuery will not trigger the click.

Comment: @adeneo yes if remove the "display:none;" it works.

Comment: @roasted the user is indeed clicking in the document. I have a div element and user has to click on it to open the color picker.

Comment: @mdoust so see my answer, replace document with your selector

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the element has click functionality because when i remove the display property from CSS, everything start working.

Comment: @roasted I'm sorry but i don't understand. User is clicking on a div element which is inside the document. I added my code to the question, so can you please let me know what exactly are you asking me to do.

Comment: @mdoust see my updated answer, this is what i mean. You cannot btw use display none, use workaround.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This need user interaction, meaning you cannot trigger it without user clicking somewhere in document:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CDG5K/)

```
$("#fontWrap").click(function () {
    $("#fontSel")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So instead of setting the 'display' property to 'none' we can get the same outcome by placing the element somewhere which in not visible to user....

Comment: ya, exactly, using position absolute e.g.

Comment: It is possible to use the jQuery as well. I only changed the style property as you instructed and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative of the accepted answer is to use `label` tag and let the browser do the work for you.

For example:

```html
<input type="color" id="my-color" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">

<label for="my-color">Click here</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works great, except **it doesn't work in MS Edge** (I personally don't like it much, but it's still 6% market share as of 2017, meaning every ~15th visitor of your website has it)

So here's a good old "hover-hack" trick that works in all browsers:

```
<input type="color" style='opacity:0;width:100px;position:absolute;'/>
<button>clickme</button>
```

And then bind `onchange` to the color element to get the selected value. Experiment with widths/heights for your layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnzm0sry/2/

PS. I know it's "hacky", but I don't have a better idea.