# manual click event only triggers on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a small color-picker module. But it only opens up (and then works) when pickColor is called a second time. I also tried to wrap the `_openColorPicker` into a `setTimeout` but that didn't work either. In fact, the color-picker didn't show up at all when I did that.

What I found interesting is that the binding to the change event works, so the $ selector must have found the element already.

So I have two questions:

1) why is the picker only showing after the second call to `_openColorPicker`?

2) why didn't the picker open at all when I wrapper the `_openColorPicker` call in a `setTimeout`?

Edit: The  `_openColorPicker` functions gets executed after the user has right-clicked into the document and then clicked on context-menu which is now showing.

Complete Code:

```
const ColorUtils = {

    _initialized: false,

    _openColorPicker: function () {
        $('#color-picker').click();
    },

    pickColor: function (onChangeCallback, context) {
        if (!this._initialized) {
            $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'color',
                id: 'color-picker',
                display: 'hidden',
                value: '#ffffff'
            }).appendTo('#centralRow');
            this._initialized = true;

            $('#color-picker').on('change', onChangeCallback.bind(context));
        }
        this._openColorPicker();

        // version with timeOut
        const scope = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
             scope._openColorPicker();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

export default ColorUtils;
```

Above code is used like `ColorUtils.pickColor(onColorPicked, this);`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729165/trigger-click-on-html-5-color-picker-with-jquery). Looks like you can't trigger a click on an invisible color picker. That answer suggests giving the element an absolute position and placing it off screen, like so:

```
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:-9999px;
```

Comment: hm that doesn't do it. still only after the second click. Also I can trigger the click, just not the first time. It works the same if I set the element to display:none for example

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your case (for what I understood) : [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/s6rtwtfp/)

I made some changes.
I moved the `$('<input/>')` in a property of the object `ColorUtils` and appended it to the DOM with absolute position and outside the screen.

(And also commented `display:'hidden'` because it's either `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` and as a CSS property, not Html attribute)

On right clic on the document I instantiate the picker (and register the callback + context) then add a button to the DOM to trigger the picker again.

Does it fulfill your requirements ?

Comment: I ended up fixing it by refactoring the code after !initialized into an init function which is called once before exporting it. The thing is I'm not 100% sure why things happen the way they do, which was my initial question. Seems nobody can give a hint

Comment: In my opinion, all the troubles come from the fact that you trigger a click event. And it can work only if it's at first triggered by a click event. That's why I appended the input to the DOM before.

Comment: well the problem is not with triggering the click event itself. Even if I use the MouseEvent constructor (which is the native Event) I get the same behavior. the question is why can I not create the element, append it and trigger the click in one call, but rather the click only triggers on the second go. as the callback works, the element was already in the dom the first time, so its not an issue of "not in the dom yet".

Comment: Not exactly because on the first click you append the element then trigger the click and on the second and next clicks you just trigger the click (because it's initialized). What I try to explain is that : https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/gxjwq5ae/ I commented the code. With or without jQuery it's the same thing : 1/ if you trigger the click in JS with no prior click event it doesn't work (`triggerClick(picker)`) - 2/ if you trigger a click on an existing DOM element it works (`triggerClick(picker)`) - 3/ if you append the element and trigger the event it doesn't work (`triggerClick(newPicker)`)

Comment: And you can't rely on the fact that the event handler is triggered because you can create an html element in JS and still attach en event handler to it and add it later to the DOM and the listener will work exactly the same way as if it was appended before : https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/8jyw2z6d/

Comment: What I'm wondering is WHY append and triggering does not work :) there must be some docs explaing the behavior ?